# "Operands could not be broadcast together", even though dimensions are identical

Tags: python, numpy

So I'm running across a really weird issue with my code. Here's the part in question:

```
vrt = np.matrix.transpose(vr) #np.shape(vrt) = (1832,360)
term2 = C*np.cos((beta*np.pi/180)-azrad) #np.shape(term2) = (1832,360)
test = np.shape(vrt) == np.shape(term2) #test = True
ci = vrt - term2

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (360,1832) (1832,360)
```

The two arrays are the same size (test = True), but when I try to subtract the two matrices, it now says that the first matrix is no longer (1832,360). When I try this without taking the transpose of vr, obviously test = False, but the error is exactly identical (ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (360,1832) (1832,360)).

Comment: I think we need a complete, self-contained example that we can run to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Assuming a few matrices for `vr` and `beta`, this code works for me